# VS 2013 Brace Completion

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I just started using Visual Studio 2013. I liked the auto brace completion feature. But in C#, when I press enter after entering {, no extra line to write our code is formed, like in eclipse. Instead the cursor will be at the left side of the }. Did anybody notice that? Is there a way to fix it.

When I press Enter key after putting brace, the editor is like this:

```
class Example {
|}
```

(The cursor is where the pipeline character is..)

EDIT:
I just found that in Visual C++ 2013, the braces work as expected.

```
class Example {
    |
}
```

(The cursor is where the pipeline character is..)

Comment: So do you want to see the open brace on the next line, or do you want to see the cursor after the open brace?

Comment: I think he wants to see class Example {\nCURSOR\n}.

Comment: Visual Studio will "clean up" formatting after the first statement you write. For example, if you write Console.WriteLine("Hello"); Visual studio will move the brace for you. I suggest you get used to it, it works quite well. Alternatively you can play with standard class templates.

Comment: I set the open brace to show up on the same line. But after pressing enter there is no new line. It is the left side of the brace as show above. i.e. in eclipse when I type a brace and press Enter, a new line is formed above the closing brace.

Comment: I should also note that I use ReSharper which can indeed be configured to create the braces and newlines as wished.

Comment: Exactly like Holstebroe said.

Comment: As @Holstebroe mentioned, it will change the formatting as you add content to the brace.  You can always tweak the formatting rules under options to your liking, though I've found the available options a bit limited.  Another option is to install VSCommands, which gives you more features for formatting, etc.

Comment: @Holstebroe Is Resharper or VSCommands the only way to get the desired result?

Comment: @thomarjos You can also configure your Visual Studio

Comment: @thomarjos, you can tweak a lot in VS, so I wouldn't be surprised if it is possible, but if not, what it does do is not completely crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Check within Options on the Text Editor/All Langauges/General page. Select "Automatic brace completion."

By the way in 2013 you can search for words like "brace" at the top of the treeview control in Options to find all the pages were "brace" is found.

Answer taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a646e2d1-aec4-4da9-a04f-6479b0b675a4/vs-2013-how-to-disable-auto-completion-in-c?forum=visualstudiogeneral).

Answer (score 0):

Try typing

```
  class
```

then press Tab.

Same goes for interface, if blocks, etc.

If you want to write a property, type

```
 prop
```

then press Tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can press Ctrl-Enter and it will reposition the closing brace as you expected. Because Ctrl-Enter makes a new line above the current line.