# Using VS Pro 2013, is there a way to tweak the 'Automatic brace completion' functionality?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Currently, within the VS C# editor, the `automatic brace completion` functionality inserts the closing paren after I type the opening paren (finishing with the cursor between the parenthesis).

e.g., `"MethodName(" == "MethodName(|)"`.

However, when I type the name of a method that takes no parameters, I want to type only the closing paren and have the editor 'insert' the opening paren (finishing with the cursor after the closing paren).

e.g., `"MethodName)" == "MethodName()|"`.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio doesn't have anything like that. You can only set to automatically complete parenthesis/braces/quotes.

You can see my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990383/vs-2013-brace-completion/21990636#21990636).

Check within Options on the Text Editor/All Langauges/General page. Select "Automatic brace completion."

By the way in 2013 you can search for words like "brace" at the top of the treeview control in Options to find all the pages were "brace" is found.

Comment: I could answer with exactly the same text but from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a646e2d1-aec4-4da9-a04f-6479b0b675a4/vs-2013-how-to-disable-auto-completion-in-c?forum=visualstudiogeneral). :)

Comment: @aloisdg Oh yes, I get the answer from this page, but I couldn't find it to link on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to type the *closing* parenthasis and have IntelliSense to kick in, you're out of luck: Visual Studio offers no such feature out of the box.

You may have some luck with third party extensions, but I doubt there's something similar.